# Oracle Hyperion Foundation Services 11.1.2.1

Tags: service, foundation, hyperion

I am new in Oracle Hyperion and I am going to download Oracle Hyperion Foundation Services  11.1.2.1 documentation.

I have searched it but I did not get write documentation.
If you have any Idea please help me.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17236_01/index.htm

The latest one is 11.1.2.2 but you may find documentation for the previous editions as well.